Literal translation of the word Παράκλητος

Is it correct to translate the word "παράκλητος" literally as "One who is called by someone else" or "one who is called (by)"?

While searching, I came across the following translation in one book:



Παράκλητος, ου, ὁ,
one called or sent for to assist another

https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/40935/pg40935.txt
Παράκλητος can really mean "one sent for to"?
Can you explain how this meaning can be derived from this word?

Thanks for the answer!
However, meanings like "send for" and "sent for" are rarely found in dictionaries, and it is not entirely clear how a word can mean both "one called" and "sent for".
What is the common denominator between these two values?

Is it correct then to translate "Παράκλητος" as "Sent by someone" "Messenger"?

"sent != sent for" -
Sorry, I don't really understand what the fundamental difference is between them.

Paraclete is a passive form, so the translation should be appropriate. Shouldn't it?

I don't know how to write messages there.
